# Mysql drop table/create table sequence gives strange error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, create-table, drop-table

This situation makes no sense.

I have the following sequence of SQL operations in my php code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename;

CREATE TABLE tablename;
```

Of course the php code does not look like that, but those are the commands being executed.

Every once in a while on the CREATE statement, the system returns "table already exists".

I would not think this could happen, unless it is some kind of delay in the dropping. The table is Innodb and I read that there could be processes using the table. However, the tablename has embedded within it a session_id for the user, because this table is somewhat transient and is dedicated to the specific user only--no other user can be using the table, and not even any other script can be using it. It is a "user-specific, script-specific" table. However, it is possible that the user could execute this script, go away to a different script, then come back to this script.

The describe code is in a routine that decides whether it can re-use the table, or whether it has to be recreated. If it has to be recreated, then the two lines execute.

Any ideas what is causing this error condition?

EDIT:

The problem with "actual code" is that sometimes it just leads to more questions that diverge from the actual point. Neverthess, here is a copy from the actual script:

```
$query1 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$_SESSION['tmpContact']}";
SQL($query1);
$memory_table = "CREATE TABLE {$_SESSION['tmpContact']}";
```

The SQL() function executes the command and has error handling.

Comment: It would be easier to comment if we could see whats really going on. Pseudo code can only ever garner guesses

Comment: Does this error always happen, or do you have more detail about specific scenarios where it happens? Is concurrency a potential issue if multiple requests come in?

Comment: You shouldn't drop and recreate a table that's hammered. It's easier to move the data to another table then delete the old data if needed.

Comment: @totalhack I was also thinking about concurrency, but he says the tablename is unique for each session.

Comment: Can you use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename`?

Comment: @ totalhack: as it says in the question "Every once in a while ...." Plus this table is specific to the user as stated.

Comment: These comments got me thinking about another possibility. Suppose the user with the dedicated table starts another browser tab. And suppose they have the same session_id() -- this might lead to my problem. I will need to check on this.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Check for errors after the `DROP`.  There may be a clue there.

Plan B:  `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...` -- That will be local to the connection, so [presumably] you won't need the `DROP`.

Comment: The temporary table does not meet the requirements, as it is a table we want to hang around for a while. We could change the design though so as not not have it hang around, which only means it has to be recreated as needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE");
if($a != ''){}else{}
```

try mixing the php with the sql.